# document.createElement() creating elements differently?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas

When I create an element like `div`, it creates closed tag also. But when I create an element like `canvas` only creates an opening tag but not closed tag. Why?

```
document.createElement('div');
```

this one creates `<div></div>`

```
document.createElement('canvas');
```

creates `<canvas>`, if I append child to it, then it creates `<canvas>childTag</canvas>`. Is there any particular reason? What elements behave like this? and What elements behave like above `div`? Did the closing tag for `canvas` is optional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only in your dev tools "markup Live View". The closing tag is there and [must](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#concept-element-tag-omission) be there.

Chrome probably does this because it won't render any content (while `<canvas>` may have some hidden content).

You can check this by calling the `outerHTML` property of your created element :

```js
console.log(document.createElement('canvas').outerHTML);
```

Comment: Can you please explain in details? for more info

Comment: Which details ? That your developer Live View tools doesn't show you the exact html as it actually is ? I think it's already in the answer. I could add that in my knowledge only chrome does this, and probably only on canvas element, because the only useful content inside a canvas element is an input one, which will gather the focus on the canvas for accessibility, and that not so many devs use this feature... but I think these details are out of focus for the question.