# mouseevent is getting fired two times over video

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

We are planning to display a button if user hovers the mouse on video. I am trying to use mouseenter event for this. But this event is getting fired 2 times. Below is the code.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="remoteVideos">
    <video id="remoteVideo"></video>
    <canvas id="localCanvas">
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#remoteVideo").on("mouseenter", function (event) {
    console.log("Mouse entered remote Video");
});
```

localCanvas will be exactly on top of remoteVideo. Now as I set the mouseenter event handler, I expect the log should be printed once when I hover the mouse on video. But mouseenter event is getting fired twice and I am able to see log 2 times. Both the times, event is exactly the same as below

```
S.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "mouseenter", target: video#remoteVideo, currentTarget: video#remoteVideo, isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, …}
```

Can any one please let me know how to fix this.

**Update:**

I noticed that after restarting the same application, I am not able to get the event at all after hovering over the video. 'mouseenter' event is really inconsistent.

Is there any event which can be fired only once and consistent when I hover on top of video. I used 'mouseover' event also. It is also getting fired twice.

Code to add localCanvas dynamically as below.

```
localCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
localCanvas.setAttribute("id", "localCanvas");
remoteVideos.appendChild(localCanvas);
```

[image]

Comment: I'd use the `:hover` CSS selector for this instead.

Comment: You're missing your closing `canvas` tag, but even with it, I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: @Brad What if the OP wants to execute JavaScript when `mouseenter` happens and not just apply styling?

Comment: @ScottMarcus That's not what the question says.  In any case, there are a handful of Chrome bugs around these mouse events right now, getting double-fired.  They're hard to reproduce... only happens to me once in awhile, but seems to be related to other software running.  I have no idea if that's the problem here or not, or I would post it as an answer.

Comment: @Brad : Is there anyway that we can achieve this in Javascript?

Comment: @ScottMarcus : I am creating localCanvas dynamically through javascript. When I use developer tools, It is not showing closing canvas tag. Not sure why.

Comment: @kadina What's the issue?  Do your action on the first `mouseenter` event, and ignore subsequent events until there is a `mouseleave`.  Or, if you're just showing something, do it on every `mouseenter` event because it won't matter if you show it twice.

Comment: Not having the closing tag could be your issue. Can you post the code you are using to dynamically create the `canvas` element? It should be `document.createElement("canvas")`

Comment: @Brad : As I mentioned in my update, some times, I am not getting mouseenter event at all.

Comment: @ScottMarcus : I updated in the post.

Comment: Added screenshot from developer tools.

Comment: @ScottMarcus : It shouldn't be a problem as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41502470/document-createelement-creating-elements-differently